# Create new SAS observations until number of observations equals other variable?

Tags: sas

I am trying to calculate attack rate in some populations using GEE, but at this time only have total number of non-cases. My dataset has individual level data for each case, and a population-wide count for number of non-cases.

In order to do the GEE, I am trying to get create non-case observations so I have one observation for each non-case.

For example:
In this starting data...

```
PopID CaseNum N_cases N_noncases   
  14    .       2        3
  14    1       .         .
  14    2       .         .
  15    .       5        2 
  15    1       .         . 
  15    2       .         . 
  15    3       .         .
  15    4       .         .
  15    5       .         .
```

I would need to create 3 new observations with PopID14 and 2 new observations in PopID 15.

so it would look like this

```
PopID CaseNum No_case  N_cases N_noncases   
  14    .         .       2        3 
  14    1         .       .        .
  14    2         .       .        .
  14    .         1       .        3
  14    .         2       .        3
  14    .         3       .        3
  15    .         .       5        2  
  15    1         .       .        . 
  15    2         .       .        .
  15    3         .       .        .
  15    4         .       .        .
  15    5         .       .        .
  15    .         1       .        2
  15    .         2       .        2
```

Once I have the non-case observations, I'm planning to separate into case-level and population-level datasets before doing my GEE in the case-level dataset.

I have tried a DO-UNTIL loop set to end when no_case=n_noncases, but it just continues forever and never stops.

```
data test1; 
set test; 
do until (no_case=n_noncases) ; 
no_case +1; 
by Popid;
output; 
end; run;
```

I am open to any and all other ways of doing this :) (I also attempted a proc sql, but that went downhill quickly because I have only ever used them to go from case level to population level data, and not vice versa)

Comment: What is your starting data set, is that what you've posted? What is the expected output? Please show them separately.

Comment: Hi @Reeza! Thanks for the questions - I just added in what I anticipate the output to look like with the way I was doing the Do-UNTIL loop.

Comment: Do you really want to keep that first extra row that is neither a CASE nor a CONTROL?  Why don't you have the value of N_CASES and N_NONCASES on every output observation?

Comment: @Tom The data will be separated out into two separate datasets - one with just the first obs (the population level data) and one with all other observations (the case level data). I don't have a particular need for each case observation to have population wide data. There are many more variables in the full dataset with population level data  that aren't shown here for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird but doable.

```
data have;
    input PopID CaseNum N_cases N_noncases;
    cards;
  14    .       2        3
  14    1       .         .
  14    2       .         .
  15    .       5        2 
  15    1       .         . 
  15    2       .         . 
  15    3       .         .
  15    4       .         .
  15    5       .         .
  ;
    ;
    ;;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by popID;
    retain nrecs;

    if first.popID then
        nrecs=N_noncases;
    output;

    if last.popid then
        do;
            N_noncases=nrecs;
            call missing(caseNum);

            do No_case=1 to nrecs;
                output;
            end;
        end;
    keep popID Casenum No_case n_cases N_noncases;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably clearer if you do it in steps.

Generate the "non-cases" .

```
data controls;
   set have(keep=popid n_noncases);
   where n_noncases > 0 ;
   do controlnum=1 to n_noncases;
     output;
   end;
run;
```

Then combine with the "cases" ;

```
data want;
   set have(where=(not missing(casenum)) controls;
   by popid;
run;
```

If performance is an issue then make the first one a data step view instead.

```
data controls / view=controls;
...
```